# Array Sort in C

Tags: c, sorting, recursion

Just curious if there is any better way to sort an array then what i have here. I know it can only sort upto 64 elements:(

And, if there is a way to reduce the BigO time of sort function itself. Maybe, just skipping those elements that are in 'last_index' could do.

Any thoughts?

```
void sort_array(unsigned short unsorted_array[] , 
                unsigned long long last_index , 
                unsigned char sort_depth , 
                unsigned char ary_len)
{
   int r, q, hold;
   r = q = hold = 0;

   for(r=0; r<ary_len;r++)
   { 
      if((hold <= unsorted_array[r]) & !(last_index & (1 <<r)))
      {
         hold = unsorted_array[r];
         q = r;
      }
      last_index |= (1 << q);

      printf("\n The value at index  [%d@%d]" , hold , q);
      puts("");
      if(--sort_depth != 0)
      {
         sort_array(unsorted_array, last_index , sort_depth , ary_len);
      }
   }//@djf This is screw-up and wont work. Please test before making changes.
}

void main(void) 
{
    int x, y;
    x = y = 0;

    unsigned short ary[10] = {123,2,23,3,5};

    sort_array(ary, x, 5, 5);
}
```

Comment: Might be more on-topic at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hate to do cross posting as much being off-topic! Can I just move this thread to that forum?

Answer (score 6):

Using [`qsort()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) is a better way, since:

- It's already written, debugged, tested and documented.
- It works, for any (reasonable) array length.
- It's library code, so it's a single function call in your application.
- Other programmers will know and trust it directly.

Comment: And `qsort()` is not limited to sorting up to 64 elements of the array.

Comment: Yup, qsort is way to go. However, the system is poor and really can't afford to include qsort thing.

Comment: @ali, what do you mean _the system is poor_? Does it not have a complete standard library implementation? Or do you think `qsort` is too heavy for your machine? Probably any implementation you write wouldn't be any lighter than `qsort`.

Comment: @Shahbaz Nope, don;t have standard lib on poor CPU and flash is expensive to be increased.

Comment: @ali, I see. If you are interested, I used to have an implementation of quick-sort with various optimizations applied to it. You can find it here: https://github.com/ShabbyX/shDS/blob/b9975eb4ad86477c5bf8a2eff9d1b4b180065855/src/vector.c#L364 Be sure to look around it for necessary macros etc

Comment: @ali, although note that that code is under GPL. If you intend to use it, you need to have a compatible license.